# Display data in crystal report in column

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to display crystal report in column pattern. I have successfully retrieved the data from student table (with a stored procedure). but want to display in this pattern

**Student Name         |          Student Name**

First Student Name    |          Second Student Name
ThirdStudent Name     |          FourthStudent Name

please tell me how can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a few steps, this will only work if you don't need to display other fields for each student.

Step 1 - Sort the data by the name you want to show on two columns.

Step 2 - Add the following formula:

```
IF (NOT(OnLastRecord)) THEN
  {StudentName} + ", " + Next({StudentName})
ELSE
  ""
```

Step 3 - Add the formula to the detail section.

Step 4 - Go into the section expert and set the suppression formula for the detail section to:

```
RecordNumber MOD 2 = 1
```