# Print records in horizontal columns

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How can I print information like this in Crystal Reports?

[image]

Comment: There is only one picture..can you add second one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display data in crystal report in column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633227/display-data-in-crystal-report-in-column)

Answer (score 0):

In general, Crystal reports is not very well configured to handle information displayed horizontally. There are some exceptions to this, but the gist is that the report is evaluated top to bottom. So any solution you can get to work will have to be out of the box (and probably a *lot* of extra work.)

If you want 3 columns, you could rig something up that displays information in your section like this by use of formulas or subreports.

> `PREVIOUS(your_field_here)` | `your_field_here` | `NEXT(your_field_here)`

You would then want to set the supression logic for that entire section as `RecordCount Mod 3 = 2` to prevent data from repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Crystal Report Designer.

Start with a blank report, use the Database Expert to choose your data fields to be used.

Manually place the header and value horizontally in the order you require. Add boxes and lines wherever required

The next set is automatically generated in the available space.

Note : If you use the portrait mode for the report, you'll get the second set below. Set the orientation to landscape to get the format in the image you have added.